What is better about Damascus River than the Jordan River?
Although Naaman was likely arrogantly biased towards his homeland and again Israel, is there a legitimate reason why the general thought the Damascus River would heal his tzara'as more than the Jordan River?
Melachim I (5:12) - הֲלֹא טוֹב אבנה [אֲמָנָה] וּפַרְפַּר נַהֲרוֹת דַּמֶּשֶׂק מִכֹּל מֵימֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל הֲלֹא־אֶרְחַץ בָּהֶם וְטָהָרְתִּי וַיִּפֶן וַיֵּלֶךְ בְּחֵמָה - Are not the Amanah and the Pharpar, the rivers of Damascus, better than all the waters of Israel? I could bathe in them and be pure!” And he stalked off in a rage.

I think he meant that he felt that if the solution was simply bathing in river-water, than he had wasted his time coming all the way to Eretz Yisrael for this. Had he known, he would have just stayed and bathed near Damascus. But he doubted that even dipping in the Jordan would purify him.
